# Is it possible to do auto-commit for github.

Tags: github

I want to be able to auto commit my work to github every lets say.. 8 hours.

Is it possible to set it up for my laptop.  i have windows machine.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's the goal of auto commit ? The goal of a commit is to *commits the staged snapshot to the project history*. You should be able to rollback to a specific commit because this commit changes made your project dirty or unstable. Auto commit-push isn't a good idea and isn't the role of git. 
**Dropbox** could be a simpler solution.